# Portable VCE Player for Windows Desktop (not Mobile)

Tags: windows, portable

I can't seem to find a single portable (i.e., No install) VCE (Exam simulator) player.

Does one not exist?

*P.S* Could anyone create the tags [windows-desktop](/questions/tagged/windows-desktop) & [vce-player](/questions/tagged/vce-player) for me (Not enough rep)?. Think it would be good to be able to tag questions as being about Windows Desktop versions (non-specific) as opposed to [windows-phone](/questions/tagged/windows-phone); And I couldn't find any tags about VCE.

Comment: I've created vce-player, but not windows-desktop. Feel free to propose creating that tag [on meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Appreciate it @Undo!

Comment: Did you find any VCE player for windows besides the one from Avanset? The only other player I could find was for Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.on_labs.android.aplus

Comment: @Schiavini I haven't found any portable versions of this software by any other company/person, but there is 1 or 2 other installed (I understand) Windows programs that are capable of reading _certain versions_ of VCE files, whose names escape me right now. I did find http://certcollection.org/forum/topic/247239-vce-exam-simulator-pro-116-windows-portable-version (there is also _useful related info_ in that page's comments), but haven't had the time to setup a VM to best-practice test for embedded malware in the software. I would prefer to find something that was ready to go without the testing